# JQ and Js how to Validate content null (Spacebar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

My JS Here:

```
  $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    var val = $('#message_content').sceditor('instance').val();
      if( val == "" || !val  ) {
            alert('Content Cannot Null');
    return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

I have one question:

How to validate? If all content is "    "(Spacebar)  or  "　　　"(full code Spacebar)...Judgment the content is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    var val = $.trim($('#message_content').sceditor('instance').val());
      if(!val) {
            alert('Content Cannot Null');
            return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

You can try this.

Comment: thanks for your demo and optimization !  Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Trim the whitespace from the input and then check it against ""

Comment: Thanks so much all. I'm Newbie of js